# encoding 737 confused

Tags: vb.net, encoding, internationalization, non-ascii-characters

I am using VB .Net  2008

Why is my conversion from ASCII to 737 (Greek DOS)  with the `Encoding.Convert` command returning readable characters, while an `IO.StreamWriter` with `Encoding.GetEncoding(737)` writes a file with non-readable characters?

I am asking this because I want to send row data to a printer which can print Greek as 737.
If I send the result of `Encoding.Covert`, I get the wrong result, while If I write a file as above and copy it to the printer is ok

Comment: Or at the very least a hexdump of the differences.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [GetEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzsz3bk3.aspx) method

```
    Dim enc As Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(737)

    Dim fs As FileStream
    fs = File.OpenRead("\737dos.txt")

    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(fs, enc)
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question at hand.